# How to compare two rows of a single Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have requirement such that I need to compare two rows of a single table and select the columns which have different values.

Primary key is Name and Status.

Sample Data:

```
Row1:  'Jack', 1, a, b, c, d, e, f
Row2:  'Jack', 2, a, b, x, d, y, f
```

So my requirement is to select x and y.
Here 'Jack' is Name and 1, 2 are status.

Comment: What do you want to select if the columns are equal, `NULL`?

Comment: also depends how many status you have.

Comment: Status will only be 1 and 2. I don't want to select equal columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
If the Columns are same 
SELECT a.col1,a.Col2 FROM (SELECT col1,Col2 FROM Table WHERE id=1 UNION SELECT col1,Col2 FROM Table WHERE id=2) a
```

other wise we can do like this also

```
select t1.value,t2.value
from Table t1
    inner join Table t2 on
        t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: first select is wrong because status always is different, but if write all columns will be good

Answer (score 0):

I think should be something like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM MainTable AS T1
INNER JOIN MainTable AS T2
    ON T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Status != T2.Status
    AND (T1.col1 != T2.col1
    OR T1.col2 != T2.col2
    OR T1.col3 != T2.col3)
```

You take matches where Name matches and Status not match, and also if at least one column not match.

Update on request:
if you want only columns, so most readable will be creating seperate selects for every column:

```
SELECT T2.col1
FROM MainTable AS T1
INNER JOIN MainTable AS T2
    ON T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Status != T2.Status
    AND T1.col1 != T2.col1
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.col2
FROM MainTable AS T1
INNER JOIN MainTable AS T2
    ON T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Status != T2.Status
    AND T1.col2 != T2.col2
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.col3
FROM MainTable AS T1
INNER JOIN MainTable AS T2
    ON T1.Name = T2.Name
    AND T1.Status != T2.Status
    AND T1.col3 != T2.col3
And so on....
```

Comment: but It will select all the columns. I want to select only different columns.

Comment: you mean like only Name, Status, Different column?

Comment: Only different columns.